# Views export in jsonapi format

Tags: views, 8

Drupal 8 offers a "REST export" views display. What would be the best way to get an export according to the [jsonapi specification](http://jsonapi.org)? Should I think in terms of creating a new views display, so the view can have a data key, and attributes, as in jsonapi format, or would it be best to modify the REST export views with a hook?

Some other approach?

Comment: i believe you can use as is without any hook. Did you try ? what is missing ?

Comment: Have a look at the [jsonapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi) module for Drupal 8

Comment: I ended up deciding to work with the REST format Drupal views provide.  It was not necessary in my case to get Drupal to provide the feed in jsonapi format.